# How to solve an error 500 in Heroku/Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

My app is working fine in localhost
but it returns error 500 when I  run in Heroku.

when i type  http://localhost:3000/proyectos/4   it displays a post with title and description  but when i type https://desarrolladorjunior.herokuapp.com/proyectos/1 it will return the error 500

```
class ProjectController extends Controller{
     public function show(Project $publication){        
        $publications = $this->projectRepository->showPublication($publication);
        return view('publication',compact('publications'));
    }
}     

class ProjectRepository {
     public function showPublication(Project $publication){
            return Project::findOrFail($publication);
        }
}
```

heroku logs

```
2020-07-14T20:43:08.544132+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=desarrolladorjunior.herokuapp.com request_id=3b0e64b9-d2b7-4128-ac0a-3fa65539f3c5 fwd="186.178.17.64" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=126 protocol=https
2020-07-14T20:43:08.544637+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.30.127.176 - - [14/Jul/2020:20:43:08 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 - "https://desarrolladorjunior.herokuapp.com/proyectos" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
2020-07-14T20:43:13.761686+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.30.127.176 - - [14/Jul/2020:20:43:13 +0000] "GET /proyectos/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 1558 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
2020-07-14T20:43:13.762016+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/proyectos/1" host=desarrolladorjunior.herokuapp.com request_id=a292fa15-713c-4538-898c-b6531428eb7f fwd="186.178.17.64" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=103ms status=500 bytes=3359 protocol=https
```

Is there anyone who solves this problem?

Comment: You need to find your PHP error logs and see what those say.

Comment: The server error log will have the details on what is causing the 500 error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Heroku but if your app is not mission critical then turn on debug in the env to get the error output.  Just remember to turn off debug afterwards.

Comment: thank u so muuch!! The error was for a variable :)